# Use the sysctlbyname function within a Linux Swift Package

Tags: swift, linux, sysctl, swift-package

i am trying to add linux support to my swift package library for system info, but i don't know how i can access the `sysctlbyname` function on linux within a Swift package.

For all of it's detections the library relies on the `sysctlbyname` function which is easily accessible by importing `Dariwn.sys.sysctl` on Apple platforms, however i can't find any Swift ways to access that function on linux, despite the fact that you can access it in C by importing sys/sysctl.h on basically any unix platform.

So i was wondering how can access that function in my Swift library on linux and if it's possible to do it without having to use C or some other non-Swift stuff, also because i'd like to keep my code compatible with the Swift playgrounds app for apple systems, which doesn't support SPM libraries featuring C imports.

Just as a reference i leave here the part of the code responsible for interfacing with `sysctlbyname` in my project:

```
import Foundation

#if os(Linux)
import Glibc //? not sure about where i can find `sysctlbyname` in linux without using C headers
#else
import Darwin.sys.sysctl
#endif

///Generic protocol to allow easy fetching of values out of `sysctlbyname`
public protocol SysctlFetch{
    static var namePrefix: String {get}
}

public extension SysctlFetch{
    
    ///Gets a `String` from the `sysctlbyname` function
    static func getString(_ valueName: String) -> String?{
        
        var size: size_t = 0
        
        let name = namePrefix + valueName
        
        var res = sysctlbyname(name, nil, &size, nil, 0)
        
        if res != 0 {
            return nil
        }
        
        var ret = [CChar].init(repeating: 0, count: size + 1)
        
        res = sysctlbyname(name, &ret, &size, nil, 0)
        
        return res == 0 ? String(cString: ret) : nil
    }
    
    ///Gets an Integer value from the `sysctlbyname` function
    static func getInteger<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_ valueName: String) -> T?{
        var ret = T()
        
        var size = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: ret)
        
        let res = sysctlbyname(namePrefix + valueName, &ret, &size, nil, 0)
        
        return res == 0 ? ret : nil
    }
    
    ///Gets a `Bool` value from the `sysctlbyname` function
    static func getBool(_ valueName: String) -> Bool?{
        guard let res: Int32 = getInteger(valueName) else{
            return nil
        }
        
        return res == 1
    }
    
}
```

And an example of how it's used in the code (of curse it's used to retrive much more stuff):

```
    ///Kernel info
    final class KernelInfo: SysctlFetch{
        
        static var namePrefix: String{
            #if os(Linux)
                return "kernel."
            #else
                return "kern."
            #endif
        }
        
        ///The os kernel name
        static var ostype: String?{
            return Self.getString("ostype")
        }

        /* Other static vars here */

    }
```

Comment: have you checked whether you have installed all required dependencies for Swift in Linux? see *Installing Swift for Linux* from https://www.swift.org/getting-started/

Comment: Hi, i am just compiling using the official swift docker image that i installed by running: `docker pull swift`. So i think i am not importing the correct libraries/headers for it.

Comment: @paulyang0125 So after some more research i found that the Darwin framework for swift, is actually included inside the Foundation libraries on apple platforms, and it provides access to the sysctlbyname functions, however inside linux there are no equivalents i know of in the standard libraries or the foundation libraries and i don't even know if i can access that stuff at all on linux to be honest without using C imports.

Comment: I feel what you target to Not using objective-c way like `#import <sys/sysctl.h>` but swift way like `Darwin.sysctl` in Linux, could be a real gap in the current Swift Kernel support for Linux. While you can still wait for gurus here to give you hints, in parallel you may think about opening an issue directly in https://github.com/apple/swift. good luck!

Comment: @paulyang0125 At the end i discovered that i can create a second package that includes a C target that can be then used as a dependency for the main package and the dependably can be used optionally depending on the platform, so this should in theory solve my issue, but the problem is that i found out that Linux has depreciated the sysctl functions, so i am afraid i have to find alternative ways to fetch my values on linux

Comment: yeah Pietro, I see this bad news (https://sourceware.org/pipermail/glibc-cvs/2020q2/069366.html). you will need to access `/proc/sys/` directory to reach what you need. [/proc/sys Manual](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/admin-guide/sysctl/index.html) ; [c programming example](https://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sysinfo/procfs_pidmax.c.html)

Comment: @paulyang0125 Yep and that's what i did at the end as you can se **[here](https://github.com/ITzTravelInTime/SwiftCPUDetect/blob/main/Sources/SwiftCPUDetect/SysctlLinux.swift)**. Thank you for the help anyway, btw check out the rest of my library, i am implementing cool stuff like rosetta detection on macOS, cpu architecture detection, easy swift-friendly access to sysctl values and a swift friendly re-implementation of uname.

Comment: Pietro, your SwiftCPUDetect Lib looks cool!  Looks forward to the successful completion of your Linux implementation - v1.4.0. Keep going :)

Comment: BTW what i am working on is version 2.0, since i have made so many changes that it's almost a complete re-write of the library and also because i had to break a lot of code to simplify things. I am looking for using it for a portable system information tool in the style of neofetch made with swift that will also include a SwiftUI universal app for apple platforms.

Comment: point taken. engineers love a portable version for system info and diagnostic tools like CPU-Z in Windows so that's a nice idea. btw when your iOS GUI app is released to App Store, let me know. I can play it around on my iPhone.

Comment: So i added an answer myself describing my solution at the end, in the hope it can help people having similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one can add C, C++ or Objective-C targets to a Swift package so it's possible to import the needed system headers, and then create some wrapper functions, that makes what is needed, accessible to Swift, but this breaks Swift playgrounds app development compatibility, since that support Swift-only targets (a possible workaround is to put the C/C++ target in a separate swift package to use it as a dependecy conditionally just for linux, for more details see the relative swift package documentation).

So adding a C/C++ target could have solved the problem, BUT the issue is that in the Linux kernel version 5.5 and onwards the `sysctl` functions have been deprecated and even on the older kernels they weren't available on all the cpu architectures Linux supports, and so on a computer running a recent kernel or some particular non-x86 cpu architecture, such Swift package would not have been built successfully.

The current way to access the information that used to be provided by the `sysctl` functions is to read it directly from the file system inside the `/proc/sys` directory and it works on all supported cpu architectures, and it's were the `sysctl` command line utility gets that data.

So only on linux the code have to modified like this, to successfully gather that data on all platforms:

```swift
import Foundation

#if os(Linux)
import Glibc //? not sure about where i can find `sysctlbyname` in linux without using C headers
#else
import Darwin.sys.sysctl
#endif

///Generic protocol to allow easy fetching of values out of `sysctlbyname`
public protocol SysctlFetch{
    static var namePrefix: String {get}
}

public extension SysctlFetch{
    
#if !os(Linux)
    ///Gets a `String` from the `sysctlbyname` function
    static func getString(_ valueName: String) -> String?{
        
        var size: size_t = 0
        
        let name = namePrefix + valueName
        
        var res = sysctlbyname(name, nil, &size, nil, 0)
        
        if res != 0 {
            return nil
        }
        
        var ret = [CChar].init(repeating: 0, count: size + 1)
        
        res = sysctlbyname(name, &ret, &size, nil, 0)
        
        return res == 0 ? String(cString: ret) : nil
    }
    
    ///Gets an Integer value from the `sysctlbyname` function
    static func getInteger<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_ valueName: String) -> T?{
        var ret = T()
        
        var size = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: ret)
        
        let res = sysctlbyname(namePrefix + valueName, &ret, &size, nil, 0)
        
        return res == 0 ? ret : nil
    }
#else
    ///Gets a `String` from `/proc/sys`
    static func getString(_ valueName: String) -> String?{
        
        let path = "/proc/sys/" + (namePrefix + valueName).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "/")

        var contents = ""
        
        do{
            contents = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
        }catch let err{
            return nil
        }
        
        if contents.last == "\n"{
            contents.removeLast()
        }
        
        return contents
    }
    
    ///Gets an Integer value from `/proc/sys`
    static func getInteger<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_ valueName: String) -> T?{
        guard let str = getString(valueName) else { return nil }
        return T(str)
    }
#endif
    
    ///Gets a `Bool` value from the `sysctlbyname` function
    static func getBool(_ valueName: String) -> Bool?{
        guard let res: Int32 = getInteger(valueName) else{
            return nil
        }
        
        return res == 1
    }
    
}
```

So at the end i figured it out on my own, i hope this can be useful to anyone having to do the same thing.